# SVG Marker does not work

Tags: javascript, svg, marker

I created a marker in javascript, It looks like below:

```
var marker = document.createElementNS(SVG.ns, "marker");
marker.setAttribute("markerWidth", "3");
marker.setAttribute("markerHeight", "3");
marker.setAttribute("id", "mkrCircle");
marker.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 12 12");
marker.setAttribute("orient", "auto");
marker.setAttribute("stroke", "#000000");
marker.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
marker.setAttribute("fill", "#ffffff");
marker.setAttribute("refX", "12");
marker.setAttribute("refY", "6");

var mkrContent = document.createElementNS(SVG.ns, "circle");
mkrContent.setAttribute("r", "5");
mkrContent.setAttribute("cx", "6");
mkrContent.setAttribute("cy", "6");

marker.appendChild(mkrContent);
defs.appendChild(marker); // <-- defs is svg defs element
```

And I used it for a path:

```
<path marker-mid="url(#mkrCircle)" d="M0,0L100,100" stroke-width="3"></path>
```

But it does not appear in the path at all, Why?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three reason causing marker to not work:

1. You haven't specified a stroke colour for your path, so it won't show up (and neither will the markers).
2. You have specified `marker-mid` markers when the path doesn't have any midpoints. It's just a single line segment. Try `d="M0,0L100,100,200,200"` to add a mid point.
3. Finally your `markerWidth` and `markerHeight` are too small (3x3) for the circle which is centred at (6,6) and radius 5. Try `markerWidth="12" markerHeight="12"`.

http://jsfiddle.net/fP5EY/

Comment: marker mid is properly working for the path but it's not working for line...can you please check it https://jsfiddle.net/dqoL07cn/

Comment: `marker-mid` does not apply to lines. Markers are placed at the start, middle and end points of an element with multiple points (path, polyline, etc).  The "mid" in `marker-mid` refers to the 2 to n-1 points in a multi-point element (path, polyline, etc). Because a line has has only a start and an end point, you can only use `marker-start` and `marker-end`.  If you want a marker in the middle of your line, you will need to split it into two lines, or use a polyline. https://jsfiddle.net/dqoL07cn/1/