# Adding marker on d3 tree layout links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add marker arrows on a default d3 tree layout. The tree layout is working fine.

I have defined the marker like this :

```
svg.append("svg:defs")
    .append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", "arrow")    
    .attr("refX", 2)
    .attr("refY", 6)
    .attr("markerWidth", 13)
    .attr("markerHeight", 13)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2");
```

and used it on the links in the tree layout like:

```
.attr("marker", "url(#arrow)");
```

But the marker arrows are not appearing. What am i doing wrong?

```js
var treeData = [{
  "name": "Top Level",
  "parent": "null",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Level 2: A",
    "parent": "Top Level",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Son of A",
      "parent": "Level 2: A"
    }, {
      "name": "Daughter of A",
      "parent": "Level 2: A"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Level 2: B",
    "parent": "Top Level"
  }]
}];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


svg.append("svg:defs")
  .append("svg:marker")
  .attr("id", "arrow")
  .attr("refX", 2)
  .attr("refY", 6)
  .attr("markerWidth", 13)
  .attr("markerHeight", 13)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2");


root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .attr("marker-mid", "url(#arrow)");;

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: First, you have to change your marker code: `svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker").data(["arrow"]).enter().append("svg:marker").//the rest here`. But this is not the only problem: You are using `marker-mid`, but your links are a unique path, with an origin and an  end. If you use `marker-end`, it will work. But for `marker` mid to work, you need to have a middle point in your paths. This is a fiddle with `marker-end`: https://jsfiddle.net/7mdcgu6t/ .But if you change to marker-mid, nothing will show up.

Comment: Related: [*"Display an arrow head in the middle of D3 force layout link"*](/q/15729856).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mid-markers do not appear because they are attached to paths with only a  start and an end vertex, no intermediate vertex.

> The marker-mid defines the arrowhead or polymarker that shall be drawn at every vertex other than the first and last vertex of the given  element or basic shape.

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/marker-mid)

What you may do instead is:

- do not show a marker (recommended, it clutters the visual without adding much value)
- use an end-marker instead of a mid-marker (and adjust the position of the last vertex so that it stay to the left of the circle, not to its center)
- or mess around with the code generating links paths, in order to add a point in the middle of the path.

Read also [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18169308).